# I am writing a program to replace some string with another string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

*Input string is something like this*

*$sim,abad_x_y,rat,2,3,a,b*
*123,456,1345*
*323,455,2433*
*$sim,abad_z_c,rat,2,3,c,d*
*123,4456,1345*
*323,4554,2445*

**Output**

*$sim,abad_x_y,rat,2,3,x,y*
*123,456,1345*
*323,455,2433*
*$sim,abad_z_c,rat,2,3,z,c*
*123,4456,1345*
*323,4554,2445*

*From second token of $sim line x,y should be taken and replaced a,b at the end*

```py
import os  
import sys  
import re  
fin=open('old_file.txt','r')  
fout=open('new_file.txt','a')  
line_list = fin.readlines() 
for w in line_list.rstrip('\n\r'):  
    if w.startswith('$sim'):  
        word_set=w.split(',')  
        split_zone=word_set[1].split('_')  
        fout=fout.write(w.replace(word_set[-1],split_zone[-1]))  
        fout=fout.write(w.replace(word_set[-2],split_zone[-2]))  
    fout=fout.write(w)  
fin.close()  
fout.close()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Actually I'm replacing the above input in text file into the the output shown below

Comment: What doesn't work (edit the question to describe what happens and what should happen)?. And please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: I also see that $sim,abad_z_c,rat,2,3,c,d  need to be replaced with $sim,abad_z_c,rat,2,3,z,c   . Is that accurate or typo?

Comment: yes that is accurate. That is what i want

Comment: @ Michael Butscher  actually I'm getting this error unindent does not match any outer indentation level at  fout=fout.write(w)

Comment: @Praneeth kindly update your answer with the error message you are getting. And kindly go through best practice for asking a question: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import sys
import re
fin=open('old_file.perf','r')
fout=open('new_file.txt','w')
line_list = fin.readlines()
for line in line_list:
    if line.startswith('$sim'):
        word_set=line.split(',')
        split_zone=word_set[1].split('_')
        new_line=line.replace(word_set[-1],split_zone[-1])
        new_line2=new_line.replace(word_set[-2],split_zone[-2])
        fout.write(new_line2)
        fout.write('\n')
    else:
        fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```